# How to monitor a Kubernetes Cluster using OpenTelemetry - Monitoring the cluster components itself

Tags: java, monitoring, open-telemetry

I understand using OpenTelemetry in Kubernetes for monitoring the pod itself, like metrics and traces, but does OpenTelemetry support monitoring the Kubernetes Cluster itself, i.e etcd, apiserver, kublet.?
Are there examples that can be shared that demonstrate this capability ?
Or do I need to use Prometheus for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are receivers for the OpenTelemetry Collector in beta or alpha right now. You should be looking at the Collector anyway for any OpenTelemetry in production.

- [Kubernetes Cluster Receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/k8sclusterreceiver). This collects cluster-level **metrics** from the Kubernetes API server. It uses the K8s API to listen for updates. A single instance of this receiver can be used to monitor a cluster.
- [Kubelet Stats Receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/kubeletstatsreceiver). This pulls pod **metrics** from the API server on a kubelet and sends it down the metric pipeline for further processing
- [Kubernetes Events Receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/k8seventsreceiver). This receiver collects events (**logs**) from the Kubernetes API server.

To help you understand the [role of the Collector, see my post](https://failingfast.io/opentelemetry/#the-collector-a-vendor-neutral-proxy).

Then you could export your metrics to something like Prometheus via [an exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/prometheusexporter) plugin to the Collector.